# Count different values in a column

Tags: count, powerbi

I would like to know if it is possible, having the first table as a result of a transformation, build a matrix with the count of ok and nok, as shown in the second table
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpivot your data; From this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Use for that a build-in function from transform ribbon "Unpivot Column"

then add attributes to rows and value to column in matrix:

And this measure to Values:

```
Measure = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Sheet3), FILTER(ALL(Sheet3), SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet3[Attribute]) = Sheet3[Attribute] && SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet3[State]) = Sheet3[State]))
```

[image]

Comment: Hej, thank you. The problem is that the fields with OK and NOK are fields calculated in the Data part on PBI. They are not in the model part on PB. And I have more fields than those in the table.

Comment: Then probably you cant get exacly this kind of output; You may try mimic this by creating multiple measures; example:

DataOK = calculate( countrows('YourTable'), FILTER(ALL('YourTable'),  var __mesureData = [YourMesureFromDataColumn] return __mesureData = "OK" ))